# How to filter a List based on a Map that have a List as value in Kotlin/Java?

Tags: java, kotlin, data-structures, filter, hashmap

I have a List of FlightCardModel having a structure:

```
val flightsList = mutableStateListOf<FlightCardModel>()

data class FlightCardModel(
    val flightCardSegmentModel: List<FlightCardSegmentModel>,
    ..
)
```

The FlightCardSegmentModel is having a structure:

```
data class FlightCardSegmentModel(
    val stops: Int,
    val departureAirportCode: String,
    ..
)
```

---

I also have a Map having a structure:

```
val segmentStops: Map<String, List<StopsButtonModel>>

data class StopsButtonModel(
    val stop: Int
    ..
)
```

I need to filter flightsList based on segmentStops Map.
The segmentStops map's keys contains the FlightCardSegmentModel's departureAirportCode.
Also, the segmentStops map's values contains the FlightCardSegmentModel's stops.
The real world implementation is that I need to filter flights(FlightCardModel) which have multiple multiple stops(take 0,1,2 stops for simplicity) at different departures(departureAirportCode).

I wrote some code like this which can only filter only one stop at a time.

```
val count = flightsList.filter {
        segmentStops.keys.all { i ->
            when (segmentStops[i]?.stop) {
                0 -> {
                    it.flightCardSegmentModel.find { it.departureAirportCode == i }?.stops == 0
                }
                1 -> {
                    it.flightCardSegmentModel.find { it.departureAirportCode == i }?.stops == 1
                }
                2 -> {
                    it.flightCardSegmentModel.find { it.departureAirportCode == i }?.stops == 2
                }
                else -> {
                    it.flightCardSegmentModel.find { it.departureAirportCode == i }?.stops >= 0
                }
            }
        }
    }.size
```

In the above code, segmentStops map is having a structure:

```
val segmentStops: Map<String, StopsButtonModel>
```

How can i filter in the above same way if the segmentStops map's values have a list? I.e:

```
val segmentStops: Map<String, List<StopsButtonModel>>
```

PS: I also need to return all items if the segmentStops map doesn't contains the departureAirportCode key or the map's value list is empty.

Thank you for reading till now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having trouble following the problem (honestly some example data and expected results for different situations would help). But your solution basically filters `flightsList`, so you only get the `FlightCardModel`s that hold a match for **every** entry in `segmentStops`, i.e. a segment with the same airport code / stop number pair? So you're looking for all the flights that contain all the segments in `segmentsList`, is that right?

(I'm ignoring the `else` statement that basically matches everything and makes the rest of the `when` block redundant, I'm assuming you are actually trying to match the stop numbers)

You can filter that like this:

```
flightsList.filter { flight ->
    segmentStops.all { (code, stopsButton) ->
        flight.contains {
            it.departureAirportCode == code && it.stops == stopsButton.stop
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what you actually want to do with a `List<StopsButtonModel>`, but assuming you're looking for *a single match* (i.e. your `segmentStops` has that particular stop number associated with the airport code) you can change it to this:

```
flight.contains { flightSegment ->
    flightSegment.departureAirportCode == code && stopsButton.any {
        it.stop == flightSegment.stops
    }
}
```

So now an entry in `segmentsList` will match if it has a matching departure code, and one of its associated stops matches.

---

I'm not really sure what you want with the bit about "returning all items" if `segmentsList` doesn't contain the destination code at all, or if it doesn't have any stops associated with the code. That seems to be the opposite of filtering on a match? Are you just looking to reject segments that **do** have the destination code and **do** have some stop numbers associated, but they're not the right numbers? Without knowing exactly what you're trying to do, I can't suggest how and where to add that logic